# Gauss-Bonnet-Chern Theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, 4-manifolds, general-relativity

I am currently doing an undergraduate project about Gauss-Bonnet-Chern Theorem. Is there any particular books/papers regarding the application of the theorem in the theory of general relativity?

Answer (score 7):

Gauss-Bonnet is used extensively in the proofs of “[no-hair](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem)” and “[positive mass](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_mass_conjecture)”:

*Israel, Werner*, [**Event Horizons in Static Vacuum Space-Times**](//doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.164.1776), Phys. Rev. 164, 1776-1779 (1967).

*Schoen, Richard; Yau, Shing-Tung*, [**On the proof of the positive mass conjecture in general relativity**](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103904790), Commun. Math. Phys. 65, 45-76 (1979). [ZBL0405.53045](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0405.53045).